# Append input of type file into form jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the piece of code that i have written,

```js
var form = $('<form/>', {action : 'myServlet', method : 'POST', name : 'myForm', id: 'myForm'}).appendTo('body');
form.append("<textarea name='description' id='description' value=''/>");
form.append("<textarea name='title' id='title' value=''/>");

$('#description').val($scope.rsp.observations);
$('#title').val($scope.rsp.title);
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Now I have to add an input of type file into this form and append, and also i have to save a file in this tag. How can this be done so that my output looks like

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="myservlet">
    <input type="file" name="attachment">
    <textarea name="description" id="description">
    <textarea name="title" id="title">
</form>
```

Here the input file type must contain a file stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You must need to select file manually to upload due to security reason, here you can create and append input field file. but can't send  hard code value or path to server.

Comment: Any other way to send file through this form as input? I have this file stored in a global variable